# Docker - yarn install: Usage Error: The project in /app/package.json doesn't seem to have been installed

Tags: docker, gitlab, yarnpkg

The following is the Dockerfile I use for a gitlab-runner pipeline to execute cypress tests.

```
FROM cypress/base:14.18.1 as dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY .yarn ./.yarn
COPY package.json yarn.lock tsconfig.json .yarnrc.yml jest.config.js .lighthouserc.json ./

COPY mailer/package.json ./mailer/package.json
COPY inventory/package.json ./inventory/package.json
COPY backoffice/package.json ./backoffice/package.json
COPY storefront/package.json ./storefront/package.json
COPY db/package.json ./db/package.json
COPY e2e/package.json ./e2e/package.json

RUN yarn

COPY mailer ./mailer
COPY db ./db
COPY inventory ./inventory
COPY backoffice/ ./backoffice/
COPY storefront/ ./storefront/
COPY e2e ./e2e

RUN cd mailer && yarn run tsc <-- Error seems to occur here
RUN cd db && yarn run tsc
RUN cd inventory && yarn run tsc

RUN yarn run e2e:run <-- this will actually run the application and the tests
```

The installation process through the `RUN yarn` command looks successful, but at the marked line I get the following error:

```
#30 [27/39] RUN cd mailer && yarn run tsc
#30 sha256:73ba143f22b6fb626fd5f0e97a5716b3ce1d9a4fbc38da1c9bf5bc940ec08299
#30 16.32 Usage Error: The project in /app/package.json doesn't seem to have been installed - running an install there might help
#30 16.32 
#30 16.32 $ yarn run [--inspect] [--inspect-brk] [-T,--top-level] [-B,--binaries-only] <scriptName> ...
#30 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd mailer && yarn run tsc]: exit code: 1
```

But the message doesn't make sense to me, as the installation command ran successfully in a previous step.

What could be the reason for this error?

**Update:**
Noteworthy is also, that this error only appears on the new gitlab-runner. On the old one, it works fine. But I can't imagine any gitlab-runner configuration that could cause this kind of error. All images used on the new runner are identical to the old runner

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever `RUN yarn install` to install the packages in the various `package.json` files, so there won't be a `node_modules` tree in the container.

Comment: (It looks like you're installing six different applications here; consider breaking this into six separate images.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Oh sorry, my bad. I accidentally cut instead of copied the `RUN yarn` command. I added it back.

Yes, each component can run alone, but since they are in the same repository separated by workspaces and depend on each other for running the tests, splitting them up would add more complexity

Comment: Do you also `RUN cd mailer && yarn` for each of the subdirectories?  Does each of the subdirectories also have a `yarn.lock` file that needs to be copied in?

Comment: @DavidMaze Usually it shouldn't be necessary, but I tried. This resulted in the same error message. There is only one lockfile in the root level which I confirmed to be present in the container's `/app` directory

Answer (score 0):

While not actually solved, I avoided the problem by switching to yarn's `zero installs` approach. With that, yarn will not complain about missing packages since the cache is also checked into the repo. It then should be copied into the Docker image as well.

More details can be found here: https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs